# Android Jsoup For Loop

Tags: android, jsoup

links and h3 are Elements.
for (Element link:links)
in Jsoup we normally do this.
How can we do it with two elements?
like for (Element link:links ; Element link1:h3)

Comment: links and h3 are lists? I would enumerate one after the other, and maybe put the treatment in a method to avoid duplication, or, if you can, add the elements from a list to the other (or to a third list that would contain the whole thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select them both at the same time and iterate over the resulting `Elements`:

```
    String html = "<a href='#'>Link</a><h3>Heading</h3><span>Some text</span>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
    for (Element e : doc.select("a,h3")) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

The output looks like this:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
<h3>Heading</h3>
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that ordering seems to be maintained, if that is important to you.

Comment: that output to be stored in a string String b=" <a href="#">Link</a>
<h3>Heading</h3>";

Comment: If you want it in a string, you should be able to do something like this: String b = doc.select("a,h3").toString();

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way - is to add al elements into one List and iterate over it:

```
links.addAll(h3);
for (Element link:links) {
//DO your stuff
}
```